# How to allow ubuntu in virtualbox access to internet while windows host is connected to VPN?

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, virtualbox, vpn

I installed Ubuntu in virtualbox under Windows 7.

It works without issue.

However, when the Windows 7 PC is connected to a VPN network, Ubuntu can no longer access the internet.

Is ther a way I can get Ubuntu to access the internet when Windows is connected to a VPN?

Comment: When you are connected to the VPN, can Windows itself connect to the internet directly?

Comment: Yes, windows itself can access internet. Actually, the VPN is to connect to company network and company internet.

Comment: So can Windows access the internet *directly*, ie not via the company internet (this is a common restriction of remote access vpn and if it is the case, then you won't be able to do what you want).

Comment: I think once VPN is connected. The only way my windows to access internet is through the company gateway.

Before VPN connection:
WIndows => INTERNET

After VPN connection:
Windows => VPN(COMPANY NETWORK) => INTERNET

Comment: Once VPN is connected, my computer even can't access other computers in my home network.

Comment: Basically the VPN client takes charge of the network card, so packets from other IP addresses appearing on the interface (such as from Ubuntu) will be discarded.  You might be able to use NAT in virtualbox rather than bridge mode, and access the company internet from ubuntu.  They would not want you to do this though.

Comment: It's already using NAT...but no lucky to connect

Comment: Just found my ubuntu can access internet. Is just slow!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way would be to configure the VM to use bridged networking instead of NAT.  Bridging means that the VM is a completely separate node on the network, with its own MAC address, so it can get its own IP address that's independent of all TCP/IP settings in the host OS.